# what is the issue between float and height:100% of divs

Tags: html, css, height

Please see the HTML below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        #MainDiv
        {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 200px;
            height: auto;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        #Contents
        {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            min-height: 100px;
            height: auto;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        #RContents
        {
            float: right;
            width: 200px;
            min-height: 50px;
            height: auto;
            border: 1px solid pink;
        }
        #LContents
        {
            float: right;
            width: 200px;
            min-height: 50px;
            height: auto;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="MainDiv">
        <div id="Contents">
            <div id="RContents">
                Right Contents
            </div>
            <div id="LContents">
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
                Left Contents
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this JSFiddle link:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rj4jf/)

What is the problem between float and height:100% in my example?

How can I force **body** , **MainDiv** and **Contents** divs To Grow With **LContents** div?

`min-height s are so important`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9TLFM/

I've cleared the floats using clear:both
and removed width and height from body

Comment: Basically with floated elements, you need to clear the float, this stretches the container element. You can find some more information and other solutions here
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 1):

just clear the floats.

Place a div at the end of both floated divs (still inside `#Contents`).

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rj4jf/1/

Comment: @MoonLight what about it? it looks fine to me.

Comment: but for me (ur fiddle - in FF and ie) body has sticked to first 100% height !

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: right` from `LContents` and it seems to work fine

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rj4jf/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try to put another div with clear:both at the end of the "Contents" div:

```
<div id="MainDiv">
    <div id="Contents">
        <div id="RContents">
            Right Contents
        </div>
        <div id="LContents">
            Left Contents
            ...                
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks / but what about body ? i want body 100% when LContents Is Too Small And Grow With LContents too!

Comment: try with min-height: 100%; for body